# How to convert mile to kilometer using kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin... I have no idea how to convert miles to kilometer

###### MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.text1)
        val ConvertButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
        val displayanswer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question about implementing unit conversion (as per the title), or about an Android app providing a UI for that conversion (as per the question body)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's really a kotlin topic.

It's simply a math problema but here is one way to implement it in kotlin :

Using kotlin extensions you can write a function to convert km to miles and miles to km :

```kotlin
fun Float.toKm() = this * 1.60934
fun Float.toMiles() = this / 1.60934
```

Now when you will have a float that represent a km you'll be able to invoke .toMiles() and when you'll have a float that represent a miles you'll be able to invoke .toKm().

Here is an example :

```kotlin
val kilometers = 10.0F
val miles = 6.0F
println("km ${kilometers} to miles = ${kilometers.toMiles()}")
println("miles ${miles} to km = ${miles.toKm()}")
```

If you want to read more about extensions : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you define `value` classes for your types. You can then add conversion functions and arithmetic operations as well. In this example I have defined the `plus` operator, but you could build on this to make this more full featured

```
@JvmInline
value class Kilometer(val value: Float) {
    fun toMeters() = Meter(value * 1000f)

    operator fun plus(other: Kilometer) = Kilometer(value + other.value)
}

@JvmInline
value class Meter(val value: Float) {
    fun toKilometers() = Kilometer(value / 1000f)
    fun toMiles() = Mile(value / 1.604f)
}

@JvmInline
value class Mile(val value: Float) {
    fun toMeters() = Meter(value * 1.604f)
}

fun useIt() {
    val km1 = Kilometer(12f)
    val km2 = Kilometer(20f)
    val km = km1 + km2
    val meters = km.toMeters()
    val miles = meters.toMiles()
}
```